# How to write the EL3 registers of ARM

Tags: arm, arm64, firmware, trustzone

Currently I'm trying to write several system control registers with EL3 privilege for my AArch64 development board.

I put my code in the trusted firmware boot loader (BL31).

Here is my code that I put in the `bl31_main` of [arm-trusted-firmware-source-code](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware):

```
asm("MRS    %x[result], SCR_EL3"
    : [result] "=r" (scr)
);

asm("MSR    SCR_EL3, %x[value]"
    :
    : [value] "r"   (scr)
);
```

I can read the values of these registers correctly so I assume my code running with EL3 privilege.

However, for several registers I tested, every time after I write new values to them, their values don't even change.

I cannot come up with what might cause this problem. Any suggestion is welcomed!

Thank you in advanced.

Simon

Comment: I'm no ARM expert, but as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44784825/2189500), I would expect the MRS/MSR instructions to need `%w`, not `%x`.

Comment: I think the docs show it is the X registers not the W.  What happened when you tried this with real assembly and not inline?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd if I use `%w` instead of `%x`, then the compiler would report error for the code so this should not be the answer for my issue, thanks.

Comment: @old_timer why would you think there is a difference between inline assembly or real one? My `MRS` returns correct value for my case so I assume my inline assembly code is running normally?

Comment: from the sheer volume of problems folks have with getting inline assembly to produce what they think it is producing.  divide the problem in half is this my C/inline assembly or is this the register I am trying to read or write?  I didnt see a disassembly of the code showing that the former was not the case.   The first debug step when something like this doesnt work is to use real assembly...(or very carefully inspect the assembly not that one blob of instructions but the entire function.

Comment: @old_timer thank you very much. Now I can write these registers successfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really insist here is a compromise...OUTSIDE of any functions, NOT within a function but in a C file.

```
asm(".globl read_SCR_EL3; read_SCR_EL3: mrs x0,SCR_EL3; ret\n");
```

...

```
unsigned int read_SCR_EL3 ( void );
```

...

```
value=read_SCR_EL3();
```

which is just another way of doing real assembly.

If you want to do inline, AFTER you have real assembly working then figure out how to get that inline like you were trying to do.  Figure out what/if you were doing wrong (which I would have hoped someone here would or will help) (I will add an assembly tag even though this is C/compiler language stuff).

do it inside a simple function that wraps the inline asm and say returns the value from the read.  DISASSEMBLE (vs -S output) the binary, find that function and inspect what the compiler produced and if it would/should work or not...Optimized it should somewhat exactly resemble the simple mrs x0,registername/ret code, maybe do something like add one to the value before returning but after reading to see that it is using/manipulating the right register...

Comment: I have no use for inline assembly, it is compiler specific and not portable and a programming language itself, so I cant help you with the details as to why your attempt didnt work...But perhaps by examining what the compiler was producing you can figure it out...start with the simple function and return then work you way up to where you wanted it placed and see if it is using/trashing the wrong register...